# SVN Subversion client

Tags: svn

Can "find" be used in SVN Subverion Client 1.7.2.

svn list --verbose -R https://svn.nam.nsroot.net:9050/svn/33561/OpicsPlus/Opics/trunk/ > Q:\Users\Dinesh\Change_Control\TortoiseSVN\commands\dj_trunk.lst

How I can I modify the above command to list only the locked objects ( that are denoted as "O" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the findstr command, 
From:  http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/windows/findstr-an-alternative-to-grep.html

> A builtin equivalent to the Unix grep command is available in Windows,
>   a bit less powerful though: findstr. You can do searches based on
>   patterns, still in a measured way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent false positives you should use the --xml switch and parse the xml output. It contains a `<lock>...</lock>` element if a file is locked.

If you can live with false positives (like if you only want to check the output manually), you can simply pipe it to find like so:

svn list --verbose -R https://svn.nam.nsroot.net:9050/svn/33561/OpicsPlus/Opics/trunk/ | find " O "

Comment: OK.. WHAT IF I WANT TO FIND ALL ENTRIES THAT IS NOT " O "

Comment: use find /v " O " to find all entries that don't contain " O ". find /? for more info.